# How much are each of the different souls worth?

Tags: demons-souls

From **Unknown Soldier** to **Renowned Hero**, plus for defeating bosses you get souls which you can use to gain various amounts of souls.
It would be nice to know how much each is worth. For example, to not spend them and have 'em wasted if you die and can't get back to your bloodstain.

The ones I know:

- Unknown Soldier: 200
- Unknown Hero: 400
- Renowned Soldier: 800
- Renowned Hero: 1000
- Storied Soldier: 2000
- Legendary Soldier: 8000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Souls you can just pick up from various places:

- Unknown Soldier's Soul: 200
- Unknown Hero's Soul: 400
- Renowned Soldier's Soul: 800
- Renowned Hero's Soul: 1,000
- Storied Soldier's Soul (or Traditional Soldier's Soul): 2,000
- Storied Hero's Soul (or Traditional Hero's Soul): 4,000
- Legendary Soldier's Soul: 8,000
- Legendary Hero's Soul: 10,000

Souls that you get from killing demons:

- Colorless demon's soul: 5000
- Beast's demon's soul: 200,000
- Doll demon's soul: 7,600
- Dragon demon's soul: 26,400
- Eroded demon's soul: 40,000
- False king's demon's soul: 60,000
- Grey demon's soul: 1,500
- Hard demon's soul: 3,200
- Hero demon's soul: 36,000
- Iron demon's soul: 4,400
- Large Flame Scale demon's soul: 30,000
- Lead demon's soul: 1,520
- Maiden in Black's demon's soul: 60,000
- Mixed demon's soul: 19,600
- Pureblood demon's soul: 48,000
- Red hot demon's soul: 18,000
- Silver demon's soul: 36,000
- Small flame scale demon's soul: 10,000
- Storm demon's soul: 48,000
- Swollen demon's soul: 13,200
- Wriggling demon's soul: 6,400
- Yellow demon's soul: 26,400

This is quite spoiler free, since you'd be hard pressed to know which demon yields which soul. You can have a look [over here](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/bosses) (where I got the list in the first place). Note that most demon souls are a shame to consume, as most can be used to get unique upgrades/spells.